# Composition of 2 functions

Tags: real-analysis

I am confused how to write the composition of $f$ and $g$. In particular for $f,g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ via

\begin{align}&& f(x)&= \begin{cases} 0& \text{if } x \in \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}, \\      
\sin(x) &  \text{otherwise,} \end{cases}&&\qquad\\
&\text{and }\hspace 4em\\
& &
g(x)&= \begin{cases} 0& \text{if } x = 0, \\      
\frac{\sin(x)}{x} &  \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: I have edited to what I think is what you want to ask. Feel free to edit it otherwise.

Comment: Do you want to write a formula for $f\circ g$?  What is the difficulty?  Do you know how to compute it?

Comment: Sir i see for g(f(x))

Answer (score 0):

In the current form \begin{align}f(g(x))&=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }\exists n\in\Bbb N, g(x)=\frac1n\\ \sin g(x)&\text{if }\forall n\in\Bbb N, g(x)\ne \frac1n\end{cases}\\&=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }\exists n\in\Bbb N,\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac1n\\ \sin\frac{\sin x}{x}&\text{if }x\ne0\land\forall n\in\Bbb N,\frac{\sin x}{x}\ne \frac1n\\ 0&\text{if }x=0 \end{cases}\\&=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x=0\lor\exists n\in\Bbb N,\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac1n\\ \sin\frac{\sin x}{x}&\text{if }x\ne0\land\forall n\in\Bbb N,\frac{\sin x}{x}\ne \frac1n\end{cases}\end{align}

since $g(x)=\frac1n$ is not satisfied for $x=0$ and any $n\in\Bbb N$.